# Salesforce outlook plugin is showing many objects when we select email template

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

We are using salesforce outlook plugin and when we want to select email template and relate to an object to bring in merge field, the drop down is showing lot of objects and there is no configuration to control the object list based on logged in user profile/permission set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are displayed based on logged in user Create and Read permissions of the objects. If the user has access to 2 objects, dropdown will show 2 objects.

Comment: This is about Salesforce Outlook add-in and not for the deprecated Salesforce for Outlook standalone windows application right? The tag on the question is kind of throwing me off.